# Convert MP3/WAV/MIDI to integer values

Tags: mp3, wav, midi

So I have a motor here and it's speed is controlled by setting a value from 0-255. In playing with it I noticed that every speed increment has a different tone to it.

I figured it would be cool if I could make this thing play music, and 255 notes should be enough to do that. There is no practical reason for this aside from fun.

So does anyone know of a library or service that will convert an MP3 or WAV or MIDI file to a series of integer values within a certain bounds?

Failing that, any suggestions on how I could program such a thing? (Java/C#/C++/whatever, language doesn't matter)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a high level concept, but using a program like ableton you could convert songs or sounds to midi with its sound-to-midi tool. At that point your midi notes are now values. You could then Send the midi values out from ableton using its output ports (ex. midi to usb port). The midi values may not be the exact number you would want to work with, so at that phase, you could create a program converting the midi values to a specific integer from 0-255.